# "Expected Declaration" Error on a blank space

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors

I created a simple class to get some data from another class which I will then show. Pretty much, Parent View Controller data will be shown in the Child View Controller. 
My error is in the Child View Controller where I am getting this "Expected Declaration" error even though I don't have any code in that area. I've tried turning Xcode on and off and re-building, but nothing seems to work.

Also, I want to point out that the error is shown on blank spaces as well, if I delete preceding code, it'll move up to to the next available character.

[image: Here's a screen shot of the Child View Controller]

Comment: Are you missing closing bracket in viewDidLoad?

Comment: is the line that causing the error the last line ?

Comment: No, I have all the brackets in place. However, The error went away once I deleted all of my code and pasted it back on.

Comment: At this picture you are missing a closing bracket for sure. You should always post your code instead of a screen shot. BTW you need to reconnect all your outlets and actions

Comment: Hypothesis: You were in fact missing the closing `}` for the `class` (as seen in the screenshot), but when you copypasted the code back in either the editor corrected it for you, or you saw from the indentation that it was missing and added it as a reflex assuming it had been omitted from the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and replace below code,

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DetailVC: UIViewcontroller {
 @IBOutlet var showMain: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet var showMain(sender: AnyObject){
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

var buttonTitle: String = ""
@IBOutlet var ratioLabel: UILabel!
var ratioValue: String = ""
@IBOutlet var comparisionLabel: UILabel!
var comparisionValue: String = ""
@IBOutlet var numerator: UILabel!
var numeratorvalue: String = ""
@IBOutlet var denominator: UILabel!
var denominatorValue: NSString = ""
@IBOutlet var ratioDescription: UILabel!
var rationDescriptionPass: String = ""

func setValuesInController()
{
showMain.setTitle(buttonTitle, forstate: .Normal)
ratioLabel.text = rationValue
comparisonLabel.text = comparisionValue
numerator.text = numeratorvalue
denominator.text = denominator
ratioDescription.text = rationDescriptionPass
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
setValuesInController
}
}
```